# c++ vector fill and output error in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, vector

The question may seem stupid, but I don’t understand why when compiling this code in visual studio, when you fill in the vector and press enter, the numbers contained in the vector are not displayed, the code seems to look correct, maybe this is due to some environment settings, tell me Please.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int x;
    vector<int> my_vector;
    while (cin >> x) {
        my_vector.push_back(x);
    }

    for (auto p : my_vector) {
        cout << p << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I tried compiling this code in Visual Studio 2022 and Visual Studio 2019

Comment: How are you going to break out of your input loop?

Comment: It is just waiting for more input. You have to figure out how to end the `while`, perhaps by testing for a special stop-value like 0, or -1, or 9999.

Comment: with your code it takes wrong input to end the while loop.

Comment: Skip the user input for now and start with `std::vector<int> m_vector{1,2,3,4,5};`. Also unlearn to use `using namespace std;` and just type `std::` where needed. (This will avoid problems in bigger projects later)

Comment: Try adding a breakpoint. Then you will see that the code does not execute to line `cout`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you also have to go out of the loop or programmatically, break the loop.

This is the fixed version of the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string x;
    std::vector<int> my_vector;
    while (true) {
        std::cin >> x;
        if (x == "") break;
        else
        {
            try
            { my_vector.push_back(std::stoi(x)); }
            catch (std::invalid_argument)
            { std::cerr << "Invalid integer!\n"; }
            catch (std::out_of_range)
            { std::cerr << "Integer too large!\n"; }
    }

    for (auto& p : my_vector) {
        std::cout << p << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you bro for your answer.I would also like to ask if it is possible to make it even easier? not to enter a string and then convert it to integers, but immediately directly fill the vector with integers?

Answer (score 0):

> not to enter a string and then convert it to integers

Here is another solution.
But, when entering   a string that starts with a number and ends with other characters, the number part will be push_back. `Eg. cin: 1qwe123. Get: 1, ignore qwe123.`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int x;
    vector<int> my_vector;

    while (cin >> x) {
        if (cin.fail()) {
            cin.clear();         
            cin.ignore(1000, '\n'); 
            break;               
        }
        my_vector.push_back(x);
    }

    for (auto p : my_vector) {
        cout << p << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```